# JavaFx text rendering outside of bounds of the root node

Tags: 3d, javafx, 2d, bounds

I have been playing around with JavaFx and trying to get to grips with the differences with 2D and 3D implementations. Right now I have been applying 2D elements to a 3D enviroment. Shapes seems to render fine where ever they are set, inside or outside the bounds of the root node. But text of any sort does not like being rendered outside the bounds of the root node.  (I have tried using a Label and a Text field). Is there any way to get text to render outside the root node?

Below example sets a red square and a label containing the text "test label" on the boundary of the root node. As you will see the boundary does not effect the red square but does so the text.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TreeRoot extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
  Rectangle square = new Rectangle();
  square.setWidth(50);
  square.setHeight(50);
  square.setLayoutX(20);
  square.setLayoutY(20);
  square.setStyle("-fx-fill: red;");

  Group sceneRoot = new Group();

  Scene scene = new Scene(sceneRoot);
  PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
  camera.setNearClip(0.1);
  camera.setFarClip(10000);
  camera.setTranslateZ(-1000);
  scene.setCamera(camera);

  stage.setScene(scene);
  stage.show();

  Label label = new Label("Test label");
  label
    .setStyle("-fx-font: 100px Tahoma;-fx-fill: linear-gradient(from 0% 0% to 100% 200%, repeat,    aqua 0%, red 50%);-fx-stroke: white; -fx-stroke-width: 1;");
label.setTranslateX(-100);
square.setTranslateX(-50);
sceneRoot.getChildren().add(square);
sceneRoot.getChildren().add(label);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  launch(args);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I've used, with a little changes from yours to clarify the problem (`StackPane` instead of `Group` and some colored backgrounds):

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Label txtH1 = new Label("Test Label");
    txtH1.setStyle("-fx-font: 60px Tahoma; -fx-text-fill: green;");
    txtH1.setTranslateY(-120);
    txtH1.setTranslateX(-240);

    Label txtH2 = new Label("Test Label Rotated");
    txtH2.setStyle("-fx-font: 60px Tahoma; -fx-text-fill: blue;");
    txtH2.setTranslateX(-240);
    txtH2.setRotate(0.001);

    Rectangle square = new Rectangle();
    square.setWidth(50);
    square.setHeight(50);
    square.setStyle("-fx-fill: red;");

    StackPane sceneRoot = new StackPane();
    sceneRoot.setStyle(("-fx-background-color: yellow;"));
    sceneRoot.getChildren().add(txtH1);
    sceneRoot.getChildren().add(txtH2);
    sceneRoot.getChildren().add(square);
    square.setTranslateY(-200);
    square.setTranslateX(-400);

    Scene scene = new Scene(sceneRoot,Color.GREENYELLOW);
    PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
    camera.setNearClip(0.1);
    camera.setFarClip(10000);
    camera.setTranslateZ(-1000);
    scene.setCamera(camera);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

To my surprise, I've found out this:

[image: Testing labels with a perspective camera]

As you can see, the green label is trimmed on the left but not on the top, and only full characters are trimmed. While the blue label, with a very slight rotation is not trimmed at all.

My guess is there's some sort of code dealing with trimming characters when possible to keep things inside the visible area... not extended to other nodes.

Have you tried a `ParallelCamera`? Both label and shape will be trimmed inside the root node, even with cutting properly characters and shapes at any point.